# Storing Loop Function Outputs into a List

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

**INPUT**

```
def mach_exp_at_year(data: ModelInputs, year):
    mach_exp_t = data.cost_machine_adv
    return mach_exp_t

for i in range(data.n_machines):
    year = i + 1
    mach_exp_t = mach_exp_at_year(ModelInputs, year)
    print(f'The machine expense at year {year} is ${mach_exp_t:,.0f}.')

for i in range(data.n_machines, data.max_year):
    year = i + 1
    print(f'The machine expense at year {year} is ${0:,.0f}.')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
The machine expense at year 1 is $1,000,000.
The machine expense at year 2 is $1,000,000.
The machine expense at year 3 is $1,000,000.
The machine expense at year 4 is $1,000,000.
The machine expense at year 5 is $1,000,000.
The machine expense at year 6 is $0.
The machine expense at year 7 is $0.
The machine expense at year 8 is $0.
The machine expense at year 9 is $0.
The machine expense at year 10 is $0.
The machine expense at year 11 is $0.
The machine expense at year 12 is $0.
The machine expense at year 13 is $0.
The machine expense at year 14 is $0.
The machine expense at year 15 is $0.
The machine expense at year 16 is $0.
The machine expense at year 17 is $0.
The machine expense at year 18 is $0.
The machine expense at year 19 is $0.
The machine expense at year 20 is $0.
```

Now I would like to create a list that stores these values. The list should read [1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

I tried creating an empty list and then appending it, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to output the desired list I showed above. Any tips?

HERES THE DATA CLASS I AM WORKING WITH

```
@dataclass
class ModelInputs:
    n_phones: float = 100000
    price_scrap: float = 50000
    price_phone: float = 2000
    cost_machine_adv: float = 1000000
    cogs_phone: float = 250
    n_life: int = 10
    n_machines: int = 5
    d_1: float = 100000
    g_d: float = 0.2
    max_year: float = 20
    interest: float = 0.05

    # Inputs for bonus problem
    elasticity: float = 100
    demand_constant: float = 300000

data = ModelInputs()
data
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: What's the purpose of `mach_exp_at_year`? It ignores its `year` argument, and doesn't do anything except wrap an attribute access.

Comment: Your final loop also appears to be confusing f-strings with format strings intended to be used with the `format` method.

Comment: `[1 if year <= 5 else 0 for year in range(1, 21)]` ֍֎֍ not clear to me what you are _really_ asking

Comment: Appending to a list is the way to go. See CodeCabbie below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just above your first loop, declare and initialise an empty list:

```
myList = []
```

Immediately under your first print statement (and in the loop) add the line:

```
myList.append(mach_exp_t)
```

and then under your second print statement (and in the loop):

```
myList.append(0)
```

Print the result right at the very bottom with:

```
print ( myList )
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Worked like a charm. I'm a python newbie (obviously), and I'm shocked at how helpful the community is. Several people responded within 30 minutes on a Monday morning. Makes me want to keep learning more! Thanks!!

Comment: If you found it very helpful, please accept my answer as the 'Accepted answer', or 'Up Vote' it. This will help others to find this answer when they see your question. Many thanks.It's a great community. Welcome.

Comment: I gave you an upvote, but it won't display because I have fewer than 15 interactions thus far. I will try to figure out how to choose you as my "accepted answer".

Comment: I have one more question if you could help. I repeated the list method that you suggested on 2 other very similar lists (ad_exp_list, scrap_val_list) (same # of values in each list) for a total of 3 lists with 20 numbers in each list. Is there a way that I can sum the values (not concatenate) of these lists so that their is one master list? Thanks

Comment: Yes. Probably easiest if you post another question, then I can give you a clear answer. BUT: In summary, you just need one loop to count upto data.max_year. In the loop add the i th value from each list to get the sum for the i th position. Append this sum to a new list.

Answer (score 0):

```
[match_exp_at_year(ModelInputs, year) if year < data.n_machines else 0 for year in range(data.max_year)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce your output, but in general below is an example of appending values to a list in Python's for loop:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(0,100):
    my_list.append(i)
```